# Why won't this HTML work?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a span text block inside a paragraph. Inside this span block I have two paragraph breaks. On webkit, the browser renders the first paragraph correctly but fails back to browser default settings on the last two. Why?

```
<style type="text/css">

span.post-content {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
}

</style>

<p><span class="post-content"> Some text here <p/> From here text loses style and adopts browser default <p/> same here </span></p>
```

This works in all browsers except Webkit based ones: chrome and safari.

Answer (score 17):

The example is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/). Fix the errors and the problem will likely go away.

1. A span element cannot include a p element
2. In HTML `<p/>` doesn't mean what you probably think it means
3. `<p/>` is not allowed in HTML Compatible XHTML
4. In XHTML, `<p>` may not contain `<p>` (nor in HTML but the end tag is optional so `<p>foo<p>bar` is valid and means `<p>foo</p><p>bar`)

You probably want something like this (and to change the CSS to reference the changed element type)

```
<div class="post-content">
    <p>Some text here</p>
    <p>From here text loses style and adopts browser default</p>
    <p>same here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can start by writing well structured HTML then see if there are any problems.

Comment: This is true, but not helpful and doesn't properly answer the question.  The OP clearly doesn't understand that his HTML is not well-formed, so it would be more constructive to explain why, rather than just criticize his code.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check your (X)HTML code here:

[validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/)

Or in Opera browser more quickly: right click -> Validate

Answer (score -1):

As David said: span cannot contain p - that is it can - but it does not make sense - because span is INLINE display type and p is BLOCK type. A span element is a line within the block ...

as ben stated: the concepts must be understood - structured or not

Comment: No, it can't. The specification forbids it. Browsers will try to error correct, how they do that depends on the browser.

Comment: It can - that is why the browsers behave differently. I did not say it was correct - I said it can - not that is makes sence.
It is the predefined display properties that makes it what it is. They introduced SPAN and DIV in order to signal that the display property sometimes is needed over the predefined HTML tags.
Anyways - I cannot find the a direct reference to the forbidden part, so maybe it is in the HTML 4.01 specs ;o)